# Get Output parameter from stored procedure without calling execute()

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, plsql, entitymanager

I want to call a PL/SQL stored procedure from within a Java program via an entity manager:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("someProcedure");
```

Now my understanding was that I have to call execute() on this storedProcedureQuery in order to execute the procedure and be able to retrieve the OUT-parameters. However, I can retrieve these values **without** calling the execute()-Method by simply calling

```
someValue1 = (Integer)storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(1);
someValue2 = (Integer)storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(2);
```

How is this possible ? When exactly will the stored procedure be executed in this code snippet? Will the procedure be executed **every** time when getOutputParameterValue() is called ? Is there any official documentation for this behaviour ?

Comment: you can find the reference here
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a new learner in his field and as curious as you with the question. However i have taken this opportunity to test it and below is my observation,

```
According to the documentation execute() returns:
> Return true if the first result corresponds to a result set,
> and false if it is an update count or if there are no results
> other than through IN OUT and OUT parameters, if any.
```

therefore I would say, the returned true or false doesn't mean a successful or not execution.

Again we must register the parameters before we call to `getOutputParameterValue`. If we looked into the implementation of `getOutputParameterValue`, we would able to find exactly where the hibernate provider ( which is JPA in case of mine) calls to the actual execution.

Further to how many times the execution happened I tested it in a way to check it by inserting to another table inside the calling procedure.

```
create table test_procedure_call(msg varchar2(100));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (
    p_in_1  IN    NUMBER,
    p_out_1 OUT   VARCHAR2,
    p_out_2 OUT   VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    insert into test_procedure_call values ('Executed..');
    commit;
    select 'FirstName'||' '||'LastName','HR' into p_out_1,p_out_2 
      from dual 
     where p_in_1=1;
END;
/

@Test
    public void testStoredProcedureQuery() {
        StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("test");
        // set parameters
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_in_1", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_out_1", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_out_2", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.setParameter("p_in_1", 1);

        String name = sp.getOutputParameterValue("p_out_1").toString();
        String dept = sp.getOutputParameterValue("p_out_2").toString();

        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        System.out.println("Department : " + dept);
    }

select * from test_procedure_call;

MSG                                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Executed..
```

By this out of the table test_procedure_call, we can confirm it executes only once per test. (as we saw in above example).